# How can I crop an image using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, html, browser, crop

Is there anyway I can crop an image using raw javascript? I want to be able to have a function that takes an image (html tag or source or whatever) with a certain width, height, offsetX and offsetY and it create a image of the portion specified.

I am not that familiar with HTML5 canvas and the like but I need to support older browsers, so that's not even an option (it sucks I know).

I hope this is clear.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to simply show the cropped portion, or do something else with it i.e. upload it? You can do the former with CSS `clip` but you can only do the latter with canvas.

Comment: Canvas seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is to display a portion of the image, use css clip: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clip . Works in IE6+ even with JavaScript disabled.

If you **need** to physically crop the image, and need IE6 support, then your options are Flash or sending the data plus cropping values to a server which returns the cropped image.

Comment: unfortunately, i need to physically crop the image. it looks like this is unfeasible using only JS.

Comment: It is possible, JS with canvas and you're done. Also, drop IE6 support.

Answer (score 4):

Often, it's enough to set the limits for rendering by using CSS styles to make the image appear cropped.

Instead of an `img`, use a `div`. Assign the desired size to the `div`. Set the property `background` to `-x -y url('...url-of-your-image...') no-repeat`

Replace `x` and `y` with the top/left offset that you want to display.

Comment: This is actually the direction i was going in. But since I was using the image (i.e. the div) a lot in my webapp, the DOM grows bigger quickly and therefore the browser performance suffers a lot.

Comment: If the image URL is the same, the browser should reuse it :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
function crop(img_id, crop_id, x, y, width, height) {
  $(crop_id).update('<img id="' + crop_id + '_img" src="' +
      $(img_id).getAttribute('src') + '" style="display:none" />');

  var scale_x = $(crop_id).getWidth() / width;
  var scale_y = $(crop_id).getHeight() / height;

  $(crop_id).setStyle({
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden' 
  });

  $(crop_id + '_img').setStyle({
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'block',
    left: (-x * scale_x) + 'px',
    top: (-y * scale_y) + 'px',
    width: ($(img_id).getWidth() * scale_x) + 'px',
    height: ($(img_id).getHeight() * scale_y) + 'px'
  });
}
```

The problem: needs Jquery, and probably the solution works in IE8+.... do you need for IE6+?

Comment: Yes I do. It seems as if this function only manipulates css to make a portion of the image show whereas I want to actually crop it. I know there are server side languages (like java) that support this, but what about javascript? I seems no for the time being.